# Can't read PHP session array if "windows authentication" is enabled on IIS

Tags: php, iis, session-variables

I try to create a small login page(site1) and the login-name should stored in the session variable. And then site 2 should read the session variable. But on site2 the session variable is empty if I enable "windows authentication" on the IIS server-> if I disable the "windows authentication" -> the session variable is filled out correct.

Is there anything else that I have to config so that I can use session variables and "windows authentication" enabled?

site1.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php include ("seitenlocation.php"); ?>
<form method="post" action="?login=1" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login">
  <input type="text" id="benutzer" name="benutzer" value="myname" required>
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

seitenlocation.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
    $benutzer = $_POST['benutzer'];
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $benutzer;
    header('Location: site2.php');
}
```

site2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo var_dump($_SESSION['uname']);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: which iis and php version you are using before and now? you could use fiddler to compare success and failure result. telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same authentication for both the site. if you use anonymous for site 1 and windows for site 2 then the session will be blank.
if you use windows for both site it will show the same session id.

[image]

[image]

[image]

in short, you need to set the same authentication for both the site.

Comment: All 3 files are in the same folder-> so I enable "windows authentication" for the folder. In your example the "echo $_SESSION['uname'];"  is also empty

Comment: like this [image1](https://i.imgur.com/x5ICh3P.png)  [image2](https://i.imgur.com/SQGxGx3.png)

Comment: Yes, all 3 files in the same folder.

Comment: Yes, I see the session id- but I need the $_SESSION['uname']

Comment: I also get the session username [image](https://i.imgur.com/qVv1H7n.gif). did you enable windows authentication for the site2.php page only? if you did that as is said you need to use the same authentication for both the page. if you use different authtication it will not work.

Comment: All 3 files are in the "auth" folder and for the "auth" folder is the Windows Authentication enabled. See [here](https://imgur.com/a/xcrUBiB)

Comment: do some simple cookie watching. See if PHPSESSID is present as a cookie on both page requests or not. do you have any rewrite rule in your site? try to use different browsers.i tested our code with ie, chrome and firefox. code is working well in chrome and firefox but not in ie.

Comment: for ie you can uncheck the "enable protected mode" so it will show the session value.

Comment: The PHPSESSID is on both sites present as a cookie. I tested it with Firefox and Edge.

Comment: I it on another IIS-> and there it woks! IIS version and PHP version is the same. Is there anything else that I have to check/config on the IIS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200554/discussion-between-inflames82-and-jalpa-panchal).

Comment: which iis and php version you are using before and now?
you could use fiddler to compare success and failure result.
telerik.com/fiddler